# generating a unique number without using central server

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I am developing a new software that have capabilities to work offline without the communication between central server on cloud. Suppose we have N nodes that communicate with local server and the local server have a connection with central service.

The network could drop anytime between the N nodes, and I want each node to be able to generate a 8 digit unique number as invoice number. Auto increment will not work in my case because node could have collision between each other.

I thought to give each node I unique three digit id, so the reaming 5 digits will be managed by the node it-self. In this case each node can generate 10^5/365 = 274 number per day, which is a small number. Is there a better way to generate I unique number assuming that each node cannot communicate to others all the time and minimize the collision rate as possible.

Comment: Give it more than 5 digits? Maybe 10?

Comment: Use a `jva.util.UUID`?

Comment: How large is `N`?

Comment: @Bohemian around 230 in some cases.

Comment: @user207421 will it be user friendly number as it will be used as invoice number.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn it is 8 digits but some are reserved even if I make it 10 I believe my logic to approach this problem is wrong

Comment: The people who designed UUIDs already faced this problem and this is what they felt they had to come up with. You're unlikely to improve on it, especially if you try to limit it to 8 digits. And of course you don't just want to minimize collisions, you want to avoid them completely, otherwise the accounts are chaos.

Comment: @user207421 uuid length is big and will not be user friendly to print it in invoice, collisions are allowed because it will be as invoice number not id, but I want to try to minimize the collision as low as possible without making the invoice number too big.

Comment: I don't think there's a practical solution to this problem in the way you've framed it.  You either need a bigger ID space -- more digits -- or you need to have the nodes talk to the server every now and then to get more IDs for themselves before they run out.

Comment: @MattTimmermans thanks I will try to think of different way to force local server to generate numbers on advance this will utilize the 8 digits without fully losing 3 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways...

Option 1: Share the ID range evenly across the nodes. Maximum new IDs per node limited to 400

To maximise the quantity of unique id’s generatable, divide the ID space up into equal parts, assigning one part to each node.

You have 230 nodes... call it a nice round 250.

Divide the into the range and you get 400 each. The next ID would be calculated as

```
int id = nodeNumber * 400 + localCounter;
```

Option 2: Cache a small amount (say 20) of IDs locally at each node, using them when off line from the main server. No limit of IDs per node.

This option is scaleable and requires only that nodes be connected often enough to keep their cache full. You would tune the number cached to be large enough that the expected time to consume all IDs is greater than the longest expected time of disconnection.

Comment: I didn't think about caching if online, so the cached ids will be reserved and the server cannot use them or assign them to different node ?

Comment: @MohdAlomar yes. The node would request a new IDs to cache from the server in the same way it would if getting a new ID to use right away. The server won’t know the difference and will believe they are used. In effect they *are* used, just not yet.